# Slim PHP Link to an anchor on another page

Tags: php, twig, slim

I am working on a website using the Slim framework. I am trying to make a link that takes the user to a specific place on the home page.

This is the normal link:

```
<a href="{{ path_for('home') }}">Home</a>
```

First I tried to write an absolute link like:

```
<a href="https://example.com#anchor">Anchor</a>
```

But this doesn't work and results in https://example.com/#anchor

This doesn't work either:

```
<a href="{{ path_for('home#anchor') }}">Home</a>
```

How can I get the link to work and take me to the specified anchor?

Answer (score 0):

The `path_for` twig extension can't handle anchors:

`<a href="{{ path_for('home') }}#anchor">Home</a>`

UPD:

```php
class DecoratedTwigExtension
{
    private TwigExtension $twigExtension;

    public function __construct(TwigExtension $twigExtension)
    {
        $this->twigExtension = $twigExtension;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (is_callable([$this->twigExtension, $name])) {
            return $this->twigExtension->$name(...$arguments);
        }

        $message = sprintf('There is no callable method %s::%s', get_class($this->twigExtension), $name);
        throw new \BadMethodCallException($message);
    }

    public function pathFor($name, $data = [], $queryParams = [], $appName = 'default', $anchor = '')
    {
        $path = $this->twigExtension->pathFor($name, $data, $queryParams);
        // some manipulations with $path
        if ($anchor !== '') {
         
        }

        return $path;
    }
}

// Register Twig View helper
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
        'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $router = $c->get('router');
    $uri = \Slim\Http\Uri::createFromEnvironment(new \Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER));
    
    // ======= the main lines =======
    $twigExtension = new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension($router, $uri);
    $view->addExtension(new \App\Namespace\DecoratedTwigExtension($twigExtension));

    return $view;
};
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work either. The page loads as example.com/#anchor instead of example.com#anchor

Comment: remove trailing slash https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/route-patterns.html or extend path_for for taking anchor argument

Comment: do you have any links that show how I can extend path_for to include anchor?

Comment: decorate or extend method https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/blob/2.x/src/TwigExtension.php#L47 and register it https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/tree/2.x#usage

Comment: look at upd, the code isn't tested, but I think the principle is clear